# How do I get required ubuntu commands while building distroless ubuntu image

Tags: docker

I created docker image for my app using official `ubuntu:20.04` docker image as base image. It consumed 300 MBs. I started exploring if I can reduce the image size further I came across chiesel by canonical. Following are some tutorial / links regarding chiesel. [1](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/teeny-weeny-containers-with-chisel-8d9bec38d124), [2](https://github.com/canonical/chisel), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMqjQ_i9eP0), [4](https://github.com/valentincanonical/chisel/blob/examples/examples/example-ssl.dockerfile). [5](https://ubuntu.com/blog/craft-custom-chiselled-ubuntu-distroless), [6](https://github.com/canonical/chiselled-base/blob/main/chiselled-base/Dockerfile.22.04) So, I started preparing distroless ubuntu 20.04 image for my app using chisel.

I tried following dockerfile:

```
ARG UBUNTU_RELEASE=20.04 CHISEL_VERSION=v0.9.0

FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_RELEASE AS chisel_ubuntu_builder

ARG TARGETARCH UBUNTU_RELEASE CHISEL_VERSION

RUN apt-get update \
    && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y ca-certificates git \
    && apt-get clean -y \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ADD "https://github.com/canonical/chisel/releases/download/${CHISEL_VERSION}/chisel_${CHISEL_VERSION}_linux_${TARGETARCH}.tar.gz" chisel.tar.gz
RUN tar -xvf chisel.tar.gz -C /usr/bin/

RUN mkdir /rootfs

RUN chisel cut --release "${UBUNTU_RELEASE}" --root /rootfs base-files_base

FROM scratch
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /rootfs /
```

I was able to build above image. But it contained empty file system. I realised that I need at least bash. But then I found that there is no chisel slice for bash for ubuntu 20.04 as can be cheched [here](https://github.com/canonical/chisel-releases/tree/ubuntu-20.04/slices). There is one for ubuntu 22.04 as can be checked [here](https://github.com/canonical/chisel-releases/blob/ubuntu-22.04/slices/bash.yaml).

So I tried source bash from other ubuntu library as follows:

```
ARG UBUNTU_RELEASE=20.04 CHISEL_VERSION=v0.9.0

FROM ubuntu:$UBUNTU_RELEASE AS chisel_ubuntu_builder
# ... same as earlier dockerfile ...

FROM scratch
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /rootfs /
# copy bash from bash_source
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /rootfs /
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /bin/bash /bin/bash
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /bin/apt /bin/apt
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /bin/apt-get /bin/apt-get
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /usr/bin/bash /usr/bin/bash
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /usr/bin/apt /usr/bin/apt
COPY --from=chisel_ubuntu_builder /usr/bin/apt-get /usr/bin/apt-get
```

I was able to build this image. But, I got following error while building my app image using above image as base image:

```
#5 [baseenv 2/4] RUN if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/amd64" ]; then     add-apt-repository -y "deb  xenial-security main"; fi
#0 0.031 /bin/bash: if [ "$TARGETPLATFORM" = "linux/amd64" ]; then     add-apt-repository -y "deb  xenial-security main"; fi: No such file or directory
#5 ERROR: process "/bin/bash if [ \"$TARGETPLATFORM\" = \"linux/amd64\" ]; then     add-apt-repository -y \"deb  xenial-security main\"; fi" did not complete successfully: exit code: 127http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntuhttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

I guess, it now contains `bash` but now does not contain `add-apt-repository`. Do I need to copy this library too to my base image? I then quickly went through my app dockerfile based on `ubuntu:20.04` image. It contained various other commands like `apt`, `apt-get`, `add-apt-repository`, `chmod`, `cd`. Do I have to copy them individually from other base image the way I am copying `bash` from  ? Also, for my app, I am cloning various third party libraries and then running their  files. Those files themselves might require other ubuntu commands.

**Q1.** Do I have to copy all such required commands from other base image?

This will be tedious since I will come to know what all things I required as and when image build fails. Then add `COPY` command to dockerfile and rebuild the image. So I want to know the recommeded procedure to build the distroless image for my app.

**Q2.** Also, is it fine to install libraries using `apt-get install` while building distroless image or it basically makes it not-so-distroless? If I should not be using `apt-get` to build distroless image, then how should I install all necessary dependency packages?

**PS:** The second image does not contain the bash also.
I get following error while running it:

```
$ docker run -it myimage /bin/bash
exec /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```

Same for `/usr/bin/bash`:

```
$ docker run -it myimage /usr/bin/bash
exec /bin/bash: no such file or directory
```